# How to use form-field of aurelia-form plugin

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm playing with forms

https://aurelia-form.spoonx.org/components.html

and I can't figure out how to display a single element using the code below
My main question is where 'element' comes from?

```
  <form-field
    value.bind="model.name"
    element.bind="nameElement">
  </form-field>
```

I tried something like this, but I can't see how to get hold of 'element'

```
  <form-field
    value.bind="userAccounts.values['name']"
    element.bind="element">
  </form-field>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form-field its for the case you want only render one field. The element is the object that describe the field, example:

```
let element = {
  key: 'name',

  /* can be excluded as it defaults to string */
  type: 'string',
  attributes: {
    /* do not allow user to change the name of the pizza */
    readonly: true,
  }
};
```

You can see more examples here: https://aurelia-form.spoonx.org/types.html

Comment: This link is no longer valid